# Co-primality of coefficients of coprime integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Given that $a,b$ are co-prime, we have infinitely many solutions for $x,y$ to the equation
>   $$ax+by=c.$$
>   Furthermore, solutions have the form: $x=ca^{-1}+tb,y=cb^{-1}-ta$.
>
> Given that $c$ can be chosen free (as can $t$), how many pairs of $x,y$ are co-prime?
>   i.e. How many pairs of $(ca^{-1}+tb,cb^{-1}-ta)$ are co-prime?

It feels like it should really be infinite because we have 2 degrees of freedom and we are trying to satisfy a linear system. Can we prove it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. For such solutions $( x, y)$ to be co-prime, it is sufficient that $c = 1$ by Euclid's gcd algorithm. The number of such solutions are infinite as can be obtained by varying the values of $t$ in your setup.

As an example, consider the equation $2x - 3y = 1$. Then all pairs of the form $( -1 + 3t, -1 + 2t)$ are solutions to this equation and are co-primes.

Of course, if there is some further restriction on the values that $x$ and $y$ can take, then it might only be finitely many.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your help @Singhal, but can we prove it? I can prove $3t-1$ and $2t-1$ are coprime using euclid's alogrithm, but the general one looks like a different beast altogether.

Comment: Any pair of numbers whose integer linear combination realizes the value $\pm 1$ on the right hand side are co-prime. This is from the definition of the gcd. That is, let $(x,y)$ satisfy $ax + by = 1$ and suppose $d = \gcd ( x, y ) > 1$. Then, $d$ clearly divides the left side $ax + by$ and therefore, it should divide the right side too, but $d > 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: You have convinced me. Maybe edit that into your answer? So we cannot have $c\neq\pm1$  right? That is if $c\neq\pm1$ , $\gcd(x,y)=c\neq\pm1$.

Comment: No, if $c \neq \pm 1$, then $\gcd ( x, y )$ need not be equal to $c$. Only if $c = \pm 1$, then the solutions $( x, y )$ are co-prime or in other words, have gcd as $1$. Let's take a re-look at the previous example.
$$2x - 3y = 2$$ Here, $c = 2$ and $(1,0)$ is a solution with $\gcd = 1 \neq 2$.

Comment: But if we are after non-trivial solutions, i.e. non-zero solutions, would it be fair to say that for $\gcd(x,y)=1$ we need $c=\pm1$?

Comment: No, $( 7, 4)$ is also a solution to the above equation with $c = 2$ and $\gcd (7, 4) = 1$. The general family of solutions, I believe, is $( 3t - 2, 2t - 2)$. The condition $c = \pm 1$ is NOT necessary but sufficient to ensure that $\gcd ( x, y ) = 1$.

Comment: Alright cheers.